# Enyo menu get overlapped z-index

Tags: menu, z-index, overlap, enyo

The problem is that is I click the button of the menu I can't see the window popup because it's hiding behind "Main Content". I can see this with Firebugs inspect element tool.

I tried using the z-index style but it doesn't seem to help..

Are there any other options or creative solutions to fix this?

```
        {kind:"FittableColumns", style:"z-index:1;", fit:true, components:[
        {kind:"FittableRows", style:"z-index:1;", fit:true, components:[
            {content:"Main Content",style:"z-index:1;", fit:true},
            {kind: "onyx.Toolbar", style: "height:40px; padding:0px;", components: [
                {kind: "onyx.MenuDecorator", onSelect: "itemSelected", components: [
                    {kind: "onyx.IconButton", src: "assets/menu-icon-bookmark.png"},
                    {kind: "onyx.Menu",style:"z-index:99999;",components: [
                        {components: [
                            {kind: "onyx.IconButton", src: "assets/menu-icon-bookmark.png"},
                            {content: "Bookmarks"} 
                        ]}, 
                        {content: "Favorites"}, 
                        {classes: "onyx-menu-divider"}, 
                        {content: "Recents"}, 
                    ]} 
                ]},  
            ]}
```

and the code goes on but that isn't anywhere near the menu to overlap.

Tkx in advance for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved added this, and did wonders `{kind: "onyx.Menu", floating: true, components: [`